# Mutiple ids on Rest Router / Zend?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-route, zend-rest

I think I have the same issue as this guy - http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-9385?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel

*"If I call something like this
/mod/con/123/abc
on a RESTful Controller I would expect, that "123" is my ID and "abc" is something else (a secondary/subsequent ID), instead "123" its the key with "abc" as value and "id" is missing at all. The ID should not get lost here and the additional parameters ... I would prefer, that they are just numbered But at least the usual behaviour (/key1/value1/key2/value2) should start behind the id-parameter."*

I need to extract the ids from the url:
    mycontroller.com/a/getdetails/123/234/345/456

Whereas Zend keeps the above as:

```
[_params:protected] => Array
    (
        [controller] => getdetails
        [action] => get
        [format] => xml
        [123] => 234
        [345] => 456
        [module] => default
    )
```

How can I treat 123, 234, 345 and 456 as ids? Or how do I extricate them from the URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You either needs to create custom routes or change your URL structure (easiest method) to something like

mycontroller.com/a/getdetails/ids/123|234|345|456

and explode on your delimiter.

Comment: damn, is changing the URL structure the more standard approach or is the custom route the way to go? any pointers on how i can work on the custom routes? zend is a new beast for me...

Comment: I would probably go the custom route, since it doesn't modify the url structure, and is more intuitive for the end user. Perhaps something like

    $route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex(
      'a/getdetails/ids/([\d|/]+)',
      array(
          'controller' => 'a',
          'action'     => 'getdetails'
      )
    );

    $router->addRoute('some_route_name', $route);

And your id's will be injected into the request object, although I think you will still need to explode on the delimeter "/" in this case.